# Managing a handle-function in R

Tags: r, api

I'm creating a package that will manage a API connection (oauth2).

The package connects to the API, gets some ticket values and stores them in a global function handle:

`handle <- function(login-details) { api-call }`

Whenever you need to get data via the api, you do it through the handle:

`getData <- function(handle) { foo }`

However, the ticket values stored in the handle expires, and the handle needs to be refreshed via some refresh-variables through the API.

The problem is, how do I do this? I can't update the handle from within the getData-function. Not unless I use some hacks (the assign()-function with the global environment).

There must be some best practices for this? Should I create a function that tests if the handle is fresh, and then returns the handle, and if not, refreshes the handle? Like:

`handle <- prepare(handle)`

`getData <- function(handle) { foo }`

This seems stupid, and would add a new possibility for errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your suggested approach is what I would do, why would this be a problem in your view?

Comment: Rather than remembering to refresh the `handle` before calling `getData`, any interface to `handle` (whether `getData` itself or possibly helper functions inside it) could always check it's fresh first.

Comment: Are you using OAuth2 authentication from httr?  Maybe you want to use a reference class?

Comment: Thanks @hadley, I remade the entire thing into setrefclass, and even though it's kind of beta, it seems to be working perfectly! Thanks for the help everybody.